# Does Seaborn's sns.load_dataset() function use real data?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, data-science

I know all of the datasets that can be loaded with sns.load_dataset() are all example datasets, used for Seaborn's documentation, but do these example datasets use actual data?

I'm asking because I want to know if it's useful to pay attention to the results I get as I play around with these datasets, or if I should just see them as solely a means to learning the module.

Comment: You are correct, there is [no licence or attribution](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/issues) of the data. You can assume those to be real data, but you cannot base any scientific conclusions on it.

Answer (score 2):

The data does appear to be real.  This is not formally documented by Seaborn, but:

- Several of the dataset are "real" well-known datasets that can be verified elsewhere, such as the [Iris dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data) hosted on UCI's Machine Learning repository.
- All of the data are sourced from https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data, and in turn from actual CSVs on Michael Waskom's (core Seaborn developer) [local drive](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/tree/master/process), it appears.  If the data were random/fake, it is more likely it would be generated by Python libraries such as NumPy.